# Не запускается безопасный режим в linux mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, grub, nvidia, cinnamon

Суть проблемы:

Перезагрузил систему, и обнаружил, уже после ввода пароля, что экран чёрный, меню (cinnamon) нет, есть только значки на рабочем столе.

Почитал форумы, пришёл ко мнению, что у меня "слетел" драйвер nVidia (в общем что-то явно с ним не то произошло, видимо после последних обновлений).

Что делал:

Снёс драйвер, и установил снова: `sudo apt install nvidia-304` и перезагрузился ... и всё.

Не то что драйвер не запускается, вообще в рабочий стол не войти, система грузится и зависает наглухо. Даже в текстовый терминал по Ctrl+Alt+F1 (-F6) не входит, мало того, ни через GRUB2 c HDD, ни через GRUB2 загрузочной флешки - загрузка в безопасном режиме начинается, но так же потом виснет наглухо, т.е. ни к одному терминалу не могу получить доступ.
Попытки загрузиться с использованием nomodset тоже ни к чему не привели.

Кто может подсказать что можно предпринять? (Переустановка - не вариант, в рабочем каталоге лежат важные файлы, бэкап которых сделать не успел, а данная домашняя папка была автоматически монтируемая и шифруемая стандартным ecryptfs).

Comment: Переустановка всегда вариант, просто не всегда лучший - с live cd/usb можно получить доступ к файловой система на жд. И даже попытаться что-то исправить там. Правда, больше ничем помочь не могу - с драйверами nvidia дела не имел, сижу на mesa.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, решение оказалось простым (напишу по шагам):

1. Загружаемся и в меню Grub2, когда выделена первая строка(стандартная загрузка ОС) нажимаем на клавиатуре англ. "e" и в открывшемся редакторе (в двух строках) указываем что нужно загружать более старую версию или более новую версию ядра Linux (в моём случае помогла именно более новая версия ядра), и находясь в том же редакторе нажимаем F10 - т.е. загружаем ОС с указанным ядром.
2. Появляется долгожданный мигающий курсор на чёрном экране, жмём Ctr+Alt+F1 и вводим свой логин и пароль.
3. Ну а теперь либо переустанавливать драйвер или выяснять, что там с ним не так было, либо примонтировать внешний диск, скопировать всю инфу а потом переустановить систему, отключив шифрование домашнего каталога! :)

Всё.